# iOS textviews not expanding in scrollview in landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, landscape-portrait

I had a view with some textviews in it that were working as I wanted. The expanded to a the same right-margin whether in landscape or portrait.

I recently have tried changing the normal view to a scrollview. I've had no luck getting these text views to expand as they once did, though. When in landscape mode everything stays huddled over on the left side with the same width as a portrait phone.

Here is some code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CGSize screen = [self handleScreenOrientation];
    [(UIScrollView *)self.view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screen.width, screen.height)];
}

- (CGSize)handleScreenOrientation {
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ) {
        return CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
    }
    else {
        return CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width);
    }
}

- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    CGSize screen = [self handleScreenOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)self.view;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screen.width, screen.height);
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The method handleScreenOrientation with the passed orientation is the same as the one w/ no parameters, just it uses the passed orientation instead of the current orientation of the status bar.

I've checked and my scrollview is set to autoresize subviews.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**: I have added

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = true;

for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
}
```

to viewdidload and willrotatetointerfaceorientation. No change.

Comment: Sounds like you need to set autoresizingMasks.

Comment: All my constraints and whatnot are the same that worked before when the superview was just a view. It only changed behavior now that it's a scrollview.

Comment: You certainly covered all the bases on autoresizingMask with your added code. Looking more closely, I think I see an answer, which I'll post below...

Comment: So you have a scroll view as the base view with one or more text views embedded in it? Do you create the view hierarchy in `-loadView`, in a NIB file or in a Storyboard?

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @JasonCoco Your understanding is correct. I built it in the storyboard.

Comment: @alivingston Yes. I guess I was unknowingly. I unchecked it and stuff wasn't positioned as nicely so I put it back.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are overriding the autoresizingMasks by forcing a change to the scrollView's contentSize. Although you have correctly noted that the screenSize is always in portrait orientation, so you reverse its dimensions for landscape, you are determining which orientation to use *before* the device actually rotates. So you're forcing the scrollView to maintain portrait dimensions in landscape.

Keep your autoresizeMask routine and discard your willRotateToInterfaceOrientation routine. Does it work now?

If not, try putting the willRotate code into *did*RotateToInterfaceOrientation.

---

Another idea:

I notice that in `viewDidLoad` you cast the container view (`self.view`) to a UIScrollView. I wonder if it might be better to leave the container view as a generic UIView, add a UIScrollView as a subview, and then add the textviews to the scrollview.

I might be out in left field here, but I've never used a scrollview directly at the container-view level, and I wonder if that might be the problem.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks for the suggestion but I haven't been able to turn it into anything productive. I changed willRotateToInterfaceOrientation to didRotateToInterfaceOrientation and switch to the no parameter version of handleScreenOrientation but no change happened. I also tried many combinations of leaving things in and taking things out but they all had no effect.

Comment: I really think all you need is the autoresizeMasks, without doing any reframing. One thing you might do as a test is set the scrollView's backgroundColor to something garish (i.e. [UIColor red]), so you can see whether it is the scrollView or the textviews that are refusing to adjust.

Comment: Yeah. I did that a while back actually. If the scrollview's bg is red then the whole screen's background is red, always. I assume that means it's doing as I want, but it has no parent view so I wasn't positive there wasn't some default behavior I wasn't aware of.

Comment: OK, then the scrollview must be adjusting as desired; the textviews must be the problem. Drat. But I have another idea. I'll edit my answer to add it...